# "Remote user is disabled" for headless Cisco AnyConnect client

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn-client

On a linux machine we are trying to establish a VPN connection using Cisco AnyConnect version `anyconnect-linux64-4.10.05085-predeploy-k9` like this:

```
printf '<user>\n<password>\ny' | /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn -s connect <host>
```

We get this error:

```
  >> state: Connecting
  >> notice: Establishing VPN session...
The AnyConnect Downloader is analyzing this computer. Please wait...
Initializing the AnyConnect Downloader...
The AnyConnect Downloader is performing update checks...
The AnyConnect Downloader updates have been completed.
  >> notice: The AnyConnect Downloader is performing update checks...
  >> notice: Checking for profile updates...
  >> notice: Checking for customization updates...
  >> notice: Performing any required updates...
  >> notice: The AnyConnect Downloader updates have been completed.
Please wait while the VPN connection is established...
  >> state: Connecting
  >> notice: Establishing VPN session...
  >> notice: Establishing VPN - Initiating connection...
  >> state: Disconnecting
  >> notice: Disconnect in progress, please wait...
  >> error: VPN establishment capability for a remote user is disabled.  A VPN connection will not be established.
  >> state: Disconnected
```

Based on comments on the internet we tried adding a profile file `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile/Profile.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnyConnectProfile xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/ AnyConnectProfile.xsd">
  <ClientInitialization>
    <LinuxVPNEstablishment>AllowRemoteUsers</LinuxVPNEstablishment>
  </ClientInitialization>
</AnyConnectProfile>
```

but to no avail.

What's the correct way to allow VPN connections for remote users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out the `AllowRemoteUser` setting has to be done **on the server side**, not the client.

Adding

```xml
<LinuxVPNEstablishment>AllowRemoteUsers</LinuxVPNEstablishment>
```

in some `.xml` file on the VPN Server made the error go away.

---

It'd be interesting to know

- why AnyConnect distinguishes between Windows and Linux clients in the first place
- why connections made from a macOS client via the AnyConnct macOS binary **did work** - are they treated as Windows / not restricted at all?

Answer (score 0):

After long hours of trying I finally found a suitable workaround for my situation for Hyper-V.

1. I enabled PSRemoting on a host from which I want to initialize a Cisco AnyConnect VPN.
2. I created a file "login_info" in "C:\temp" with this content:

> connect {vpn_endpoint}
> {username}
> {password}

3. I create a powershell script "any.ps1" with this content:

> cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility
> Client"
> Get-Content "C:\temp\login_info" | .\vpncli.exe -s

4. Then I connected to the host from my system through PS Remoting:

> $cred = Get-Credentials
> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName {hostname_or_IP} -Credential $cred

5. I ran ".\any.ps1" script. This action disconnected me from PS Remoting but the RDP session was still active.
6. I checked the status with the command "vpncli.exe status" inside the
   directory "c:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure
   Mobility Client" and the connection was active.